# incorrect c++ enum indentation in emacs 26.x

Tags: indentation, c++

My emacs 26.3 insists on a very strange enum indentation even when started with  --no-init-file --no-site-file

```
 
class A {
public:
  enum EnumWithLongName {
                         val0,
                         val1,
                         val2
  };
};
```

Comment: What is the question? It could be "how do I stay with emacs 26.3 but customize the formatting?" or it could be "how do I upgrade to a version of emacs that indents this thing better?" or it could be "Why is it doing this?" or it could be any number of other questions. So please be specific.

Comment: "Incorrect" formatting with respect to which indentation style?  cc-mode supports a vast array of different styles.  IIRC the gnu style is the default.  Is this incorrect for gnu style, or just different to your personal preferences?

Comment: Previous versions had reasonable defaults of 2 or 4 spaces from the previous indent not something that is determined by the length of the type name.

Comment: That's what I get with emacs 27 or 28  and `emacs -Q` (I don't have a 26.3 available, so I can't test with your version). Depending on what your question actually is, that could be an answer: upgrade to 27 or later.

Comment: How hard is to backport this fix? For a lot of environments (ubuntu, debian) 26 is the default? Can it be patched by creative config?